# Log4j skipping content while writing to file

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I've got a Spring Boot application with the following log4j2.xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="getworks-backend.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="warn"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="warn"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

And I've got a warn message writing like

```
log.warn("Unexpected token {}", accessToken);
```

It appears on the console, but not in my log file.
If I change `AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="warn"` level to `level="info"` it writes log messages to file, but only those that were not written by loggers in my classes.

Some parts of my build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
dependencies {
    //log4j2
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.11.0'
    //other dependencies
}
```

How can I make log4j2 not to ignore my logs while writing to file?

P.S . I am using `@Log4j2` lombok annotation to generate my `log` object, but if I am doing it in classic way nothing changes.

Comment: What happens if you set immediateFlush="true"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set immediateFlush=false, the output is buffered. Eventually the output will be flushed after more messages, but I would remove that statement. ImmediateFlush is true by default.